# XPath last() does not work properly

Tags: c#, xpath

I have following xml

```
 <root>
    <data>
      <person>tewst</person>
      <data>
        <phone>djk</phone>
        <email>dsd</email>
      </data>
    </data>
  </root>
```

Using c# SelectSingleNode I am trying to get to **second** "data" node and insert the new element call "phone2" after email tag. 
Issue is I can not get to the correct "data" node. This is the code I am using to get there and it does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
XMLDocument doc = new XMLDocument("xml file here");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//data[last()]");

XMLElement phone1 = doc.CreateElement("phone2");
phone1.InnerText = "12";
node.AppendChild(phone1);
```

Problem is that node is null.

Solution:

```
XMLDocument doc = new XMLDocument("xml file here");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("(//data)[last()]");
```

Comment: The problem could be that the second node `data` is a child of the first one. You should change the node name, or change the method to access it, reading node by node.

Comment: I can not change the structure of the xml since this is by design and it is consumed by third party webservice.

Comment: Then I suggest you the second solution, access the structure node by node, using methods like `node.Descendants(XName.Get("node_name"))`

Comment: You can try with brackets around `//data`, i.e. `(//data)[last()]`

Comment: Thanks!! (//data)[last()]                                             This did work!

Comment: Great @hss. I posted a more detailed answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//data[last()]` selects `data` nodes that are their parent's last `data` child, so it selects 2 nodes in your example:

1) last `data` child of the `root` node

```
<data>
    <person>tewst</person>
    <data>
        <phone>djk</phone>
        <email>dsd</email>
    </data>
</data>
```

2) and last `data` child of the first `data` node

```
<data>
    <phone>djk</phone>
    <email>dsd</email>
</data>
```

To select the last `data` in the whole document, use:

```
(//data)[last()]
```

- `//data` will generate the node-set for all descendant `data` elements, nested or not,
- `[last()]` will select the last node of the node-set
- with the brackets `()` around `//data`, it ensures it's interpreted as `//data` then `[last()]`, instead of  `//` then `data[last()]`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways you can do this.

(1) If you know that the structure of the XML will always be like the above - "root" element, exactly one "data" child, and exactly one "data" child beneath the "data" parent, you can access the second "data" element directly using the XPath expression:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/data/data");
```

(2) If there are multiple "data" elements beneath the "root" element, then you can do the following:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//data/data");
```

This XPath expresion will return the first "data" element beneath every top level "data" element in the document. So for instance, if you had an XML document like this:

```
<root>
    <data>
      <person>tewst</person>
      <data>
        <phone>djk</phone>
        <email>dsd</email>
      </data>
    </data>
    <data>
      <person>two</person>
       <data>
        <phone>bbb</phone>
        <email>ddd</email>
       </data>
    </data>
</root>
```

... the output of this code snipped:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//data/data");

foreach (XmlNode parentData in nodeList)
    Console.WriteLine(parentData.InnerXml.ToString());
```

... will produce:

```
<phone>djk</phone><email>dsd</email>
<phone>bbb</phone><email>ddd</email>
```

Hope this helps.